# auto fill authentication script

Tags: authentication, dom

Hey guys I have a very interesting question about some basis of DOM. I have hosted a website recently but the host is password protected and you have to authenticate to access my website :D  Do anybody know a script that tells the browsers about authentication(username and password). you can check my website as demo that needs authentication www.targetmodel.co.cc

thank you guys , I really need your supports :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your domain www.targetmodel.co.cc is not a real domain name, it's just use iframes to show your acttual website. So try to configure your domain name to open website:

```
http://prefillUsername:prefillPassword@fueled.co/demo/users/aniltiwari/new/
```

it should help you
Good luck

Comment: Hey thanks for your instant response :) Can you please figure our this code http://prefillUsername:prefillPassword@fueled.co/demo/users/aniltiwari/new/ and where should I place this ?